# Hashtable with integer key in Java

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm trying to create a Hashtable as in the following:

```
Hashtable<int, ArrayList<byte>> block = new Hashtable<int, ArrayList<byte>>();
```

but I am getting an error on both int and byte saying "Dimensions expected after this token".

If I use something like:

`Hashtable<String, byte[]>` - all is good. Can someone explain why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Java's core collection classes you can only store reference types (something that extends a java.lang.Object). You *cannot* store primitives like `int` and `byte`. Note that an array like `byte[]` is no primitive but also a reference type.

As @Giuseppe mentioned, you can define it like this:

```
Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<Byte>> table = new Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<Byte>>();
```

and then put primitive `int`'s in it as keys:

```
table.put(4, ...);
```

because since Java 1.5, [autoboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) will automatically change the primitive `int` into an `Integer` (a wrapper) behind the scenes.

If you need more speed (and measured the wrapper collection classes are the problem!) you could use a 3rd party library that can store primitives in their collections. An example of such libraries are [Trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/) and [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/).

Answer (score 0):

Java generics can't be instantiated with primitive types. Try using the wrapper classes instead:

```
Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<Byte>> block = new Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<Byte>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Integer instead of int and if you're using java 1.5+ the boxing/unboxing feature will make your life easy when working with it.

```
Hashtable<Integer,byte[]> block = new Hashtable<Integer,byte[]>();
```